# Manufacturing date of computer running on Windows 7 onwards

Tags: windows, operating-system, bios, hardware

I am working on an application for our IT support team. For one of the requirement, I need to find out the manufacturing date of a laptop (and some desktops). I did some googling and found some solutions but none of them are feasible in my case:

1. Serial Number :  get the serial number from the back of the machine and access the vendor's site with given serial number and get all the details.
   -> This is not going to work because there are hundreds of machines and from many vendors like Dell, HP, Lenovo, etc.
2. Operating System : I can extract all the OS level info by using "systeminfo.exe". There is a field called "Original Install Date" which will give a date when OS was installed on the machine.
   -> This is also not going to work for me because whenever a laptop is assigned to a new user, it is being formatted and fresh OS image is being deployed so everything this date will change.
3. BIOS : In one of the articles it is being stated that because BIOS is installed as soon as the assembly is finished so it can provide the most accurate date when the machine was ready to end user use after installing OS. So I have used "Win32_Bios" WMI class to extract this data.
   -> The problem with this approach is whenever any BIOS version upgrade happens, this BIOS date is also getting modified, so I cannot get the real manufacturing date of the machine.
4. Last approach, I thought if I can get the processor manufacturing date then I might get some approximate date when the machine came into existence. I checked Device Manager --> Processors --> Properties.
   -> Problem with this approach is, I am seeing the version and date of the processor driver and not the real processor and this date is showing way back from 2006

I would really appreciate if someone please share their views or experiences regarding the above situation.

I know this kind of the question has been asked before and it has been closed down because people thought it is not very interesting topic to discuss so I really request to all please do not close this question. Let's give a chance to everyone to share their views.

Thanks.